# Is AWSmobile-cli discontinued?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-mobilehub

When attempting to initilaise awsmobile cli, it says development is being discontinued, switch to AWS Amplify cli.

AWS mobile was fantastic, in that it setup all the backend components i needed automatically. No need to use a templated project.

How on earth does AWS Apmlify help you do this easily for React Native projects??I need S3, Cognito, DynamoDB (which is less than half the price of AppSync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup - looks like it's being discontinued.

[On their site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/aws-mobile-cli-reference.html) they recommend using [Amplify CLI instead](https://aws-amplify.github.io/)